# Sign PDF with one signature, but with several signature appearances

Tags: c#, itext

I want to sign a pdf with *one* signature with appearance *on every page*

Here is what I do:

Create the stamper

```
 PdfStamper st = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, new FileStream(this.outputPDF, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write), '\0', null, true);
```

Get the signature appearance

```
PdfSignatureAppearance sap = st.SignatureAppearance;
```

populate the properties

```
 sap.SetCrypto(...);
 sap.Reason = SomeString;
 sap.Contact = SomeString;
 sap.Location = SomeString;
```

Each stamper has one appearance. I am able to set only signature appearance. Has anyone done something like that? Do I have to create a List of Stampers or a List of SignatureAppearances?

Answer (score 2):

A single `PdfSignatureAppearance` is always associated with a single page and it's not possible to add more than one annotation to a signature object.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is possible but not recommended and forbidden starting with PDF 2.0. But there are examples in the wild describing it in more detail:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35701597/how-to-show-digital-pdf-signature-in-all-documents-page-using-itext), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47526151/how-to-place-the-same-digital-signatures-to-multiple-places-in-pdf-using-itextsh/47762053#47762053) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49446542/placing-signature-in-multiple-location-on-same-page-while-signing-a-pdf).