# How to add one global digital signature with visualization (text based) on each page of pdf using pfx file in java

Tags: java, pdf, digital-signature

I am able to add text based visible digital signature on one page of pdf using DynamicPDF but not able to add on all pages. However requirement is to add one digital signature and its text based visualization on all pages of pdf.

Earlier, to add empty place holder for digital signature I was able to add on all pages of PDF using PDFBox, however PDFBox do not support text based visible signature on pdf. 
Can someone please help which library can help me to add visible text based signature on all pages of pdf in java?

Comment: You can find a discussion of the technical options in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35724742/1729265). (The *"upcoming PDF 2.0 standard"* mentioned there meanwhile has been published, so the linked consideration is not an abstract musing but a concrete issue of your requirement.) (As an aside: You say *"PDFBox do not support text based visible signature on pdf."* which in my eyes is false.)

Comment: This  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35701597/how-to-show-digital-pdf-signature-in-all-documents-page-using-itext/35724742#35724742) , suggests to do changes in iText class, from where this source code is available? Such changes would be feasible for commercial purpose? Is there any other API available ?

Comment: *"This answer , suggests to do changes in iText"* - no. The answer is to a question focussed on iText, so the answer also considers the special case iText; mostly, though, it discusses options for multiple visualizations in general, not for a special library. Of particular interest should be that the new pdf standard ISO 32000-2 prohibits single signatures with multiple visualizations. Thus, you should first of all discuss with the person requiring that whether you really want that, i.e. an application already obsolete when created, whether another option presented in that answer would do, ...

Comment: ... whether another option presented in that answer would do, or whether multiple visualizations are necessary at all. Only when that is clear, you should care about how to implement the chosen solution and using which libraries.