# PDFBox multiple location on single user signature

Tags: java, pdfbox

I want to ask, can a single user have multiple location signature but just one in signature panel ? [image: img1]

it is possbile ?

[image: img2]

Comment: Please share that PDF that you think has two signature locations.

Comment: no, i mean i want to create like that, is possible ?

Comment: No, there's only one appearance for a signature. But you could of course create two placeholders (i.e. empty signature fields) and then sign only one of them.

Comment: Well, you can make PDFBox create a signature with multiple widgets but according to the current PDF spec (ISO 32000-2:2020) such structures are invalid. Validators working according to the (very!) old ISO 32000-1:2008, though, may accept such signatures. And there also are a number of validators that don't care. The PDFBox example code works according to spec and does not create multi-widget signatures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is possible however forbidden starting with PDF Spec 2.0.
In smaller PDF versions it is possible to have one signature field (what you call "just one in signature panel") with multiple widgets.

There are several threads here on SO describing it in more detail:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35701597/how-to-show-digital-pdf-signature-in-all-documents-page-using-itext), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47526151/how-to-place-the-same-digital-signatures-to-multiple-places-in-pdf-using-itextsh/47762053#47762053) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49446542/placing-signature-in-multiple-location-on-same-page-while-signing-a-pdf).

Please note that the examples are using iText as a PDF library. (So the code using PDFBox looks different and might not be possible out of the box)